# Приведение типа T в RotateTransform

Tags: wpf, vb.net, типы, transform

В такой функции привожу T к другим трансформациям:

```
Public Shared Sub SetTransformForDrawingGroup(Of T As Transform)(newTransform As T)
  ...
End Sub
```

Не могу понять почему не дает преобразовать Т к RotateTransform или другим трансформациям?

Comment: А как приводите? Как бы не всякая `Transform` есть `RotateTransform`

Comment: Через `CType`.
`CType(transform, RotateTransform)`

Comment: На вход как раз приходят только `RotateTransform`, `TranslateTransform` и `ScaleTransform`

Comment: Перед преобразованием проверяйте, действительно ли пришло `RotateTransform`, иначе `CType` будет вполне справедливо бросать `InvalidCastException`. Ну или используйте `TryCast`

Comment: @АндрейNOP Мне это необходимо (как мне кажется) для того, чтобы сложить углы из новой трансформации к некой другой, например, при использовании `RotateTransform`.

Comment: @АндрейNOP я даже до компиляции не могу дойти, т.к. сразу при написании кода пишет невозможно преобразовать.

Comment: Точно, есть же еще `TryCast`.